# Why can't I add local users after leaving a domain?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I've got a Windows 7 machine that used to be part of a domain. After leaving the domain and changing it back to a workgroup, I can no longer add users through the user accounts screen. I have the password for the local administrator and the output of "net localgroup administrators" includes this account on there.

Has anyone run into this before and if so, what did you do to fix this?

Comment: What error are you receiving exactly?  My only assumptions is your not actually logging into an Administrator account.

Comment: No errors, it acts like it worked but doesn't do anything. I even enabled the hidden administrator account and got the same results

Comment: Also of note is that no users show up in the manage users window...

Comment: How did you "leave" the domain exactly?

Comment: System > change name name change from domain to workgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not able to resolve why the user accounts menus were not working, I was able to find a work around by adding the users from the command prompt using the following commands:

```
net user USERNAME PASSWORD /add
net localgroup administrators USERNAME /add
```

This allowed me to add a new user to the administrators on the local computer and move on.